ANY 3rd Party Solutions for creating/managing Staking/Yielding program for own SPL-tokens?
Are there any 3rd party solutions (eg. Metaplex, Helius etc.) that provide simple tooling for creating and managing staking/yielding programs for own SPL-tokens?
